# Binding a component to an element declared in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a Menu and a TabbedGroup. When I click on one of the menu options, I want to add a LayoutPanel to the TabbedGroup.

I have the elements inside MainWindow:

```
<view:UCMainMenu Grid.Row="1"/>

<dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
    <dxdo:LayoutGroup Orientation="Horizontal">
        <dxdo:TabbedGroup Name="MainTabbedGroup">                   
        </dxdo:TabbedGroup>
    </dxdo:LayoutGroup>       
</dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
```

The problem is that the menu is a UserControl with its own ViewModel.The MainWindow has his own ViewModel too. I have the TabbedGroup created in a property in the Menu ViewModel, but I don't know how to bind it to the MainWindow TabbedGroup element.

I have a TabbedGroup in the UCMainMenu ViewModel:

```
public TabbedGroup MainTabbedGroup { get; set; }
```

And when I click on a menu option, I add a LayoutPanel to this TabbedGroup:

```
new TileViewModel()
{
    Caption = "Menu View",
    NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
    {
        LayoutPanel layoutPanel = new();

        MainTabbedGroup.Add(layoutPanel);
    })...
```

In the Main Window I try to binding the TabbedGroup to the element in the Menu of the ViewModel, but I get an error:

```
((MainWindowViewModel)this.DataContext).Window = this;

((MainMenuViewModel)DataContext).MainTabbedGroup = this.MainTabbedGroup;
```

And I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'IntERP.App.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel' to type 'IntERP.App.ViewModels.MainMenuViewModel'.'

How can I bind it?

Comment: A `UserControl` is not supposed to have its own view model. It supposed to inherit the `DataContext` from its parent element. And why do you have a `TabbedGroup` property in a view model? This defeats the whole purpose of the MVVM design pattern. And obviously you cannot ever cast a `MainMenuViewModel` to a `MainMenuViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i would advise you not to access controls inside your viewmodel. This bypasses the whole reason that you use viewmodels. For one thing, it makes testing viewmodels a whole lot more difficult. It's better to put this logic (of adding to the tab group) in the code behind of the MainWindow.

But regarding your code: you want to cast the DataContext to a MainMenuViewModel while it a MainWindowViewModel.

What you could do: do the binding in the XAML itself:

```
<view:UCMainMenu Grid.Row="1" MainTabbedGroup="{Binding ElementName=MainTabbedGroup}"/>
```

but again, the viewmodel should not be concerned with changing the visual tree.